# Segmentation fault when accessing elements of pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "frac_heap.h"

#define ARRAYSIZE 10
#define ENDOFARRAY 999

fraction heap[ARRAYSIZE] = {0};
block freeBlocks[ARRAYSIZE] = {0};
int startingBlock = 0;
int nextFree = 0;
fraction* fracPointers[][ARRAYSIZE] = {0};
block* blockPointers[][ARRAYSIZE] = {0};

void init_Heap(){
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < ARRAYSIZE; x ++){    
        block *currBlock = &freeBlocks[x];
        currBlock->isFree = 1;  
        fraction *fractionPointer = &heap[x];
        if(x<ARRAYSIZE - 1){
            fractionPointer->denominator = x+1;
        }
        else if(x == ARRAYSIZE - 1){
            fractionPointer->denominator = ENDOFARRAY;
        }
    }
}

void dump_heap(){
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < ARRAYSIZE; x ++){
        fraction* tempFrac = &heap[x];
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n",tempFrac->sign, tempFrac->numerator, tempFrac->denominator);
    }   
}

fraction* new_frac(){

    fraction* testFraction = &heap[0];
    if(testFraction->numerator == 0 && testFraction ->denominator==0){
        printf("Before return");        
        return testFraction;
    }
}

int main(){

    init_Heap();
    dump_heap();
    fraction *p1;
    p1 = new_frac();
    p1->sign = -1;
    p1->numerator  = 2;
    p1->denominator = 3;
    dump_heap();
   }
```

I get segmentation faults when trying to call new_frac(). At this point im just testing the code and I realize that testfraction wont always be = &heap[0];. However, I thought I was able to access parts of the struct that I am point to with '->'?

After editing it some more, it seems to only segfault when it reaches testFraction->denominator. If I only check for the denominator it still segfaults, but it works fine with just the numerator.

Comment: You have to allocate memory. Memory management in c in not default

Comment: your first reaction when you get a crash, such as segmentation fault, should be to run the program in a debugger. It will show you exactly where the crash happened, let you see the call-stack so you know how you ended up there (and can go back to your code if the crash happens in a system function), and also let you examine variables to help you figure out what might have caused the crash.

Comment: Right, but if I change it to if(testFraction->numerator== 0) it works. But If I change it to if(testFraction->denominator == 0) it segfaults

Comment: Your function `new_frac` MUST always return something. You might add a `return NULL;` after your if block and of course, check the returned value in your main after the call `p1 = new_frac();`

Comment: @silentboy The OP is taking a pointer to a structure in an array, so it's already allocated.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that not all code paths through `new_frac()` actually return a value. You then proceed to assign through this potentially uninitialized pointer:

```
p1 = new_frac();
p1->sign = -1;
p1->numerator  = 2;
p1->denominator = 3;
```